# Disabling the textbox not working

Tags: javascript

*I am writing small form, so jQuery is out of game here.*

Question is, why this code don't want to work?

```js
function isChecked() {
  if (document.getElementById("priceCall").checked) {
    document.getElementById("mailingPrice").setAttribute("disabled", false);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mailingPrice").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  }
}

var priceCall = document.getElementById("priceCall");
priceCall.addEeventListener("change", isChecked);
```

```html
<h2>Costs of sending? (point if yes)</h2>
Mailing price:
<input id="mailingPrice" type="text" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="priceCall" onchange="isChecked()">
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Note that there is typo in `addEeventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `disabled` property on the element directly. For example:

```
element.disabled = true;
```

If you change that in your code, it works fine:

```js
function isChecked() {
  if (document.getElementById("priceCall").checked) {
    document.getElementById("mailingPrice").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mailingPrice").disabled = true;
  }
}

var priceCall = document.getElementById("priceCall");
priceCall.addEventListener("change", isChecked);
```

```html
<h2>Costs of sending? (point if yes)</h2>
Mailing price:
<input id="mailingPrice" type="text" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="priceCall" onchange="isChecked()">
<br>
<br>
```

This is just a little extra, but you can simplify this down:

```js
function isChecked() {
  document.getElementById("mailingPrice").disabled = !this.checked;
}

var priceCall = document.getElementById("priceCall");
priceCall.addEventListener("change", isChecked);
```

```html
<h2>Costs of sending? (point if yes)</h2>
Mailing price:
<input id="mailingPrice" type="text" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="priceCall" onchange="isChecked()">
```